# What is a better approach for operating on an arbitrary map value in Scala?

Tags: scala

Coming from an imperative background, I have written the following code in Scala.  I need to attempt to find a value in a map.  If the value exists, I need to pass the value to another function and return the result, otherwise I need to return None.

```
def foo(index: Int): Option[FooBar] = {
  val mylookup: Map[Int, String] = this.generateMap()
  var out: Option[String] = None

  if (mylookup.containsKey(index)) {
    out = Some(mylookup(index))
  } else if (mylookup.containsKey("static_value")) {
    out = Some(mylookup("static_value"))
  }

  if (!out.getOrElse("").isEmpty) {
    return this.doSomeCall(out.get).makeFooBar()
  } else {
    return None
  }
}
```

I don't feel like this is the best way to accomplish this in Scala.  Any ideas on how to approach this using the idiomatic nature of the language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myLookup.get(index).orElse(myLookup.get(static_value)).map { doSomeCall(_).makeFooBar }
```

From the Scala doc of [`Option.map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option):

> Returns a scala.Some containing the result of applying f to this scala.Option's value if      this scala.Option is nonempty. Otherwise return None.

This is exactly the type of task functional programming is made for. This simple chaining of `Option`s using `map` is related to the fact that `Option` is a monad.

Comment: That is indeed terse.  However, how do I return a single value?  I'll modify my code above to not be as implicit.  I want to return the value from makeFooBar.

Comment: Ignore my last comment as I understand how that works now.  However, how would I check for my static value if the index value doesn't exist?

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the part with `static_value`.  I changed my post.